# Javascrtipt file added via Add As Link available in published version but not debug

Tags: javascript, visual-studio

In Visual Studio I have a solution that consists of several different projects. I would like to consolidate some javascrtipt into a common project that then is added to the other projects via `Add Existing Item > Add as Link`.

I've successfully added the file to the consuming projects and all is great in the published version. **However**, when debugging or running in dev mode the file throws a 404 not found. As the file is found in the published version, this tells me there is nothing inherently wrong with the path.

I've set `Copy Always` for *Copy to Output* directory.

I suspect that as the file has been added as a link there is no physical file available in the debug directory.

What is the best way around this? Ideally I would still be add as a link and not using "Add" which makes a copy of the file, mostly defeating the purpose of the common library.